# Illustrator stroke throwing spacing off?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, line-art

I am trying to create simple lines that are horizontally evenly space. I don't think it's so much the stroke.

I tried using the `align` panel and distribute spacing horizontally, but it's not working?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try creating it in a bigger artboard or in a bigger size (may be more than 500x500)

Answer (score 1):

Could this perhaps be a `Pixel Grid` issue?

Try selecting all the lines and making sure this check box is unchecked:

[image: Align to Pixel Grid]

Answer (score 0):

That's strange.  What I would do is expand the lines so they become solid shapes then you can distribute them using the align panel.